# Sending objects as signal arguments between threads in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and trying to learn the Qt threading mechanism. I am in a situation where I would like a background thread to perform some long running task and report the results to another (or main) thread after processing every 100 items. Right now I am doing this by emitting a signal from the background thread containing a list of the processed objects that is received in a slot in the main thread. Does Qt make a copy of the signal argument when it is received in the slot ? If so, how does how does calling `qRegisterMetaType` help with that ? This is what I am tying to accomplish in my code :

```
//background thread
void run(){
   //get a query object from database
   int fireCount = 0;
   QList< QList<QVariant> > data;
   while(query->next()){
        fireCount++;
        QList<QVariant> row;
        //do some calculations on the fields read from the query
        processRow(query,&row);
        data.append(row);
        if(fireCount>100){
            emit publishDataToMainThread(data);
            fireCount = 0;
            data.clear();
        }
   }

}

//slot in main thread
void receiveData(QList< QList<Qvariant> > data){
\\display the data
}
```

Also , is this a recommended practice for transferring objects between threads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly fine way of doing it. QList uses implicit sharing (i.e. copy on write) so copying it means copying one pointer and increasing the reference count. It only gets copied once you try to modify it.
Just remember to use [Qt::QueuedConnection](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) when connection the signal to the slot so that the slots gets run in the receivers thread.

`qRegisterMetaType` or `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` are needed so that you can pass parameters by value in signals. It tells the Qt Metatype system (which is sort of like reflection) that this type exists.

Comment: Also maybe using `data = QList< QList<QVariant> >()` instead of `data.clear()` might save an unnecessary copy. But maybe that is unnecessary, I didn't look at the source code of `clear()`

Comment: There's only one reliable way to save an unnecessary copy, and that's C++11 move semantics. But given that Qt still doesn't support C++98 templates, that might be a bit optimistic. Still, in general `.clear()` is more efficient in the short term.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, `clear()` internatlly just calls `*this = QList<T>()`.